# Apache2 mod-rewrite редирект

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

Как сделать чтоб при вводе
**mail.mysite.ru**
отображался сайт из парки 
**mail.mysite.ru/mail/**

Comment: @Drakonoved по данному вопросу-  странная реакция. был задан конкретный вопрос. и получен конкретный ответ, дополненный вариантом из другого сайта. если кому-то не понятен вопрос - не надо ничего писать, noname2019 понял вопрос и кратко толково ответил.

Answer (score 1):

в корневой папке сайта в файле htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ mail/     [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) mail/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

есть ещё варианты
если сделать папку сайта видимой

```
Redirect permanent "/" "/mail/"
```

если скрыть папку сайта

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mail"
```